# When does each action corresponds to a homomorphism and an anti-homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If I adopt for function evaluation and function composition the convention $f(x)$ and $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$, and if $G$ is a left group action on some set $X$, then to this left action their corresponds naturally a homomorphism from $G$ to $Sym(X)$ by setting
$$
 \varphi_g(x) := gx
$$
and an Anti-Homomorphism by setting $\psi_g(x) := g^{-1} x$. Likewise to each right action their corresponds a Homomorphism and an Anti-Homomorphism.

In some general algebraic structure, where just some composition and an identity element is given, each left action corresponds to a homomorphism, and each right action to an anti-homomorphism,  I think it is not possible to associate a anti-homomorphism to a right action. So in what settings (algebraic structures) is this possible, besides for groups?

Comment: For a right action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ it is $xg$ that is defined not $gx$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, I meant left but wrote right (I edited it), if we have a right action, then $\varphi_g(x) := xg$ gives an anti-homomorphism, as $\varphi_{gh}(x) = x(gh) = (xg)h = \varphi_h(xg) = \varphi_h(\varphi_g(x)) = (\varphi_h \circ \varphi_g)(x)$, but for a left action the definition $\varphi_g(x) := gx$ gives a homomorphism w.r.t. the way I write function application and composition.